# How to pass extra options from template to the view in Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm using [django-voting](https://github.com/pjdelport/django-voting) application to let users vote on objects, and it works fine. But now that turns out there are more than one model to be voted, I decided to send extra options dynamically from template to the view to make it more generic and usable. But it doesn't work.

views.py

```
def vote_on_object(request, model, direction, post_vote_redirect=None,
        object_id=None, slug=None, slug_field=None, template_name=None,
        template_loader=loader, extra_context=None, context_processors=None,
        template_object_name='object', allow_xmlhttprequest=False):
```

at the moment urls and template is like this and it works:

urls.py

```
link_dict = {
    'model': Link,
    'template_object_name': None,
    'allow_xmlhttprequest': True,
}
url(r'^links/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$', vote_on_object, link_dict, name='vote_link'),
```

template.html

```
<form class="vote" method="POST" model="{{ object | model | lower }}" id="{{ object.pk }}" action="{% url 'vote_link' object_id=object.pk direction="up" %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit"> + </button>
</form>
```

but when I change urls and template as below to send model dynamically to the views:
urls.py

```
link_dict = {
    'template_object_name': None,
    'allow_xmlhttprequest': True,
}
url(r'^vote/(?P<model>[-\w\d\_]+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$', vote_on_object, link_dict, name='vote_link'),
```

template.html

```
<form class="vote" method="POST" model="{{ object| model |lower}}" id="{{ object.pk }}" action="{% url 'vote_link' model=object|model object_id=object.pk direction="up" %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit"> + </button>
</form>
```

I get following error: `"POST /vote/Link/1/upvote HTTP/1.1" 500 11350`

Also I should say model filter is a filter I've defined to extract model of object inside template.

Here's vote.js which handles AJAX voting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //listen for click
    $('form.vote').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var vote_el = $(this);
        var
            url = vote_el.attr('action'),
            model = vote_el.attr('model'),
            direction = vote_el.attr('direction'),
            object_id = vote_el.attr('id'),
            allow_xmlhttprequest = "True" ;
            console.log(allow_xmlhttprequest, url, model, direction, object_id);
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: vote_el.attr('action'),
                data: {
                    'model': model,
                    'object_id': object_id,
                    'direction': direction,
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log("Voted");
                    var pk = object_id;
                    $("p."+model+"-"+pk).text(data['score'].score);
                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: 500 could be anything. You should look in your browser dev tools for the actual error reported by Django.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined` so I think there might be a problem in voting.views, right?

Comment: That is an error in the JS (in the success function, presumably), not the one that is being reported by Django.